# Automatic FTP file transfer to and from Linux machines

Tags: linux, ftp

Is it possible to copy files to my Linux machine from another Linux machine automatically with FTP? By "automatically," I mean that FTP would need to handle submitting a login/password combination, as well as copy files, on its own.

Both machines run Red Hat 5.1. I want to get, for example, the file `/root/file` from the second Linux machine onto my machine and put it under `/var/tmp` without entering any login/password manually.

I don’t have `expect` on my machine, and I don't want to use SSH authentication.

If this can't be done automatically by FTP, please suggest an alternate solution, such as a Python script.

Comment: Use [key based SSH authentication](http://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password) and SCP.

Comment: sorry I dont want to use SSH authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `lftp` client program and use an FTP script.

---

`lftp` supports the [`~/.netrc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc) configuration file, in which you can store your credentials:

```
machine <hostname> login <user> password <password>
```

You can store a sequence of FTP commands in a file and have `lftp` execute them, like:

```
open <hostname>
cd /var/tmp
put /root/file optional_new_filename
```

The path in `cd` is on the remote host, the first argument to `put` is the local file.

Then, just run

```
lftp -f <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always store the credentials in a file and pass them as an argument to the script which is calling the FTP command, however I would recommend using SFTP (FTP over SSH) instead with key-based authentication [as per my reply](https://superuser.com/questions/354048/is-there-a-way-to-log-into-a-machine-using-ssh-without-password/354126#354126) to another post. Key-based authentication is more secure and your data & login channels will be encrypted.

Comment: please give me example

Comment: An example would largely depend on how you're trying to do the transfer and what you are doing. Your post didn't provide enough of those details for me to give a detailed example in return.

Comment: all I want is to get the /root/file from linux2 machine and copy this file to my linux1 under /var/tmp without login=root/password=pass123

Comment: Setup SSH key auth and use `rsync -e ssh` in a simple Bash script to copy the file. E.g. `rsync -avH -e ssh root@linux2:/root/file /var/tmp/`

Comment: your example not good because need the password entering, the target is to login & password auto

Comment: Please re-read my initial post.